# Removing admin javascript

Tags: javascript, scripts

I'm having some trouble adding [jquery-week-calendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) to WordPress' admin interface using `add_menu_page` and other API methods. What I found out is that the default `jquery-ui` and other JavaScript references are interfering in the rendered calendar behavior.

How can I remove these extra scripts from the admin interface? `load-scripts.php` is called a couple of times, and I can't seem to deregister the scripts that the admin components like tinyMCE and others are calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `load-scripts.php` file, scripts that are not enqueued will not be loaded, so I don't need to worry about it when using hooks like `admin_enqueue_scripts` and the `wp_deregister_script` function.

```
foreach( $load as $handle ) {
    if ( !array_key_exists($handle, $wp_scripts->registered) )
        continue;
```

However, my problem with jQuery week calendar was with the `wp-jquery-ui-dialog` style. So, to solve this problem I just had to:

```
wp_deregister_style('wp-jquery-ui-dialog');
$scripts = array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget',
    'jquery-ui-mouse', 'jquery-ui-resizable', 'jquery-ui-draggable',
    'jquery-ui-button', 'jquery-ui-position', 'jquery-ui-dialog');
foreach ($scripts as $s)
    wp_deregister_script($s);
```